# jQuery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am using the following for a custom message for validation failure but I am getting the default message...What is wrong? or am I missing something? I get the default message ...but not my custom message

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
            rules: {
                insurance1_ucBuildingInsurance_txtOtherReasonDescription: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                insurance1_ucBuildingInsurance_txtOtherReasonDescription: { required: "Please enter a other reason........." }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Does the element have a `class="required"` on it?

Comment: yes I do have a required class on the textbox using CSSClass property of ASP.NET textbox

Comment: I have multiple classes on the textbox namely class="txtOtherReasonDescription required" as the output in the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you appear to be using ASP.Net from the naming convention, give this a try instead:

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
  rules: {
    insurance1$ucBuildingInsurance$txtOtherReasonDescription: "required"
  },
  messages: {
    insurance1$ucBuildingInsurance$txtOtherReasonDescription: { 
      required: "Please enter a other reason........." 
    }
  }
});
```

The validation plugin expects the *name* of an element, not the ID, so use `.UniqueID` rather than `.ClientID` to get the control names here.